# The size for values of type `[char]` cannot be known at compilation time

Tags: rust, compiler-errors

I have the following Rust code ...

```
const BINARY_SIZE: usize = 5; 
let mut all_bits: Vec<[char; BINARY_SIZE]> = Vec::new();

let mut one_bits: [char; BINARY_SIZE] = ['0'; BINARY_SIZE];
all_bits.push(one_bits);

for i in [0..BINARY_SIZE] {
    let one = all_bits[0];
    let first_ok = one[0];  // This works, first_ok is '0'
    let first_fail = one[i]; // This works not
}
```

How can I get from the variable 'one' the i'th character from the array?

The compiler gives me for let first_fail = one[i]; the error message ..

*error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[char]` cannot be known at compilation time*

Comment: Have you tried following the advice given by the compiler? If you aren't seeing it, be sure that you are looking at the output from `cargo build` rather than just errors listed in your IDE, because those don't give you the full picture.

Comment: That won't help him. His actual problem is that `for i in [0..BINARY_SIZE]` is iterating over a slice of `Range`s, rather than the range values.

Comment: @PitaJ It won't solve the *next* problem, but it is the first step in basic debugging/troubleshooting and will allow him to move forward.

Comment: @Herohtar, yes, I tried to follow the advice of the compiler, but this did not help me (I#m new in Rust) and in regard of PitaJ's answer I kind of understand why. The whole output of the compiler is

help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `[char]`
   = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
   = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
help: consider borrowing here
   |
26 |         let first_fail = &one[i]; // This works not

so the suggestion was to take the & operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using the Range syntax incorrectly. By wrapping `0..BINARY_SIZE` in brackets, you're iterating over the elements in a slice of `Range`s, rather than iterating over the values within the range you specified.

This means that `i` is of type `Range` rather than type `usize`. You can prove this by adding `let i: usize = i;` at the top of the loop. And indexing with a range returns a slice, rather than an element of your array.

Try removing the brackets like so:

```
const BINARY_SIZE: usize = 5; 
let mut all_bits: Vec<[char; BINARY_SIZE]> = Vec::new();

let mut one_bits: [char; BINARY_SIZE] = ['0'; BINARY_SIZE];
all_bits.push(one_bits);

for i in 0..BINARY_SIZE {
    let one = all_bits[0];
    let first_ok = one[0];  // This works, first_ok is '0'
    let first_fail = one[i]; // This works now
}
```

The error here really doesn't help much. But if you were using a helpful editor integration like rust-analyzer, you would see an inlay type hint showing `i: Range`.

Perhaps the rust compiler error message here can be improved to trace back through the index type.

Comment: yes, taking away the brackets solved my problem and now first_fail is also of type char (and not [char]).